# Shorten line without moving arrowtip in PGF 3.0

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows

I have this arrow style in PGF/TikZ 3.0:

```
\tikzset{myline/.style={double distance=0.8pt, line width=0.4pt, -{>[length=2.5pt,width=4pt]}}}
```

It produces this result:

[image: Double line with arrow tip]

As you can see, the double line overshoots the arrow tip. How can I adapt my style to shorten the double line? Of course I want the tip of the arrow to stay in the same place:

Comment: Please, use the Imgur interface for the picture. Just click on the “image” button and upload the picture.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Solution 2:** This is a solution using `decoration` with `\arrow` and shorten path.

```
\documentclass[varwidth,border=20]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\tikzset{
  myline/.style={double distance=0.8pt, line width=0.4pt, -{>[length=2.5pt,width=4pt]}},
  myline2/.style={shorten >= 1.4pt,
    double distance=0.8pt, line width=0.4pt, postaction=decorate,
    decoration={
      markings,
      mark=at position 1 with {\arrow{>[line width=0.4pt, length=2.5pt,width=4pt]}}
    }
  },
  point/.style={insert path={node[circle, inner sep=.1pt, draw=red, ultra thin]{}}}
}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[transform canvas={scale=2}]
    \draw[myline] (-.25,.1) to[bend left] (.25,.1) [point];
    \draw[myline2] (-.25,-.1) to[bend right] (.25,-.1) [point];
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Solution 1:** This is a solution using `decoration` with shifted `\arrow`.

```
\documentclass[varwidth,border=20]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\tikzset{
  myline/.style={double distance=0.8pt, line width=0.4pt, -{>[length=2.5pt,width=4pt]}},
  myline2/.style={
    double distance=0.8pt, line width=0.4pt, postaction=decorate,
    decoration={
      markings,
      mark=at position 1 with {\arrow[xshift=1.4pt]{>[line width=0.4pt, length=2.5pt,width=4pt]}}
    }
  },
  point/.style={insert path={node[circle, inner sep=.1pt, draw=red, ultra thin]{}}}
}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[transform canvas={scale=2}]
    \draw[myline] (-.25,.1) to[bend left] (.25,.1) [point];
    \draw[myline2] (-.25,-.1) to[bend right] (.25,-.1) [point];
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this proposal. It seems that this moves the arrow tip, however, am I right? I need the arrow tip to stay in the same place, but the line to shorten.

Comment: @JamieVicary Ok, here is the second solution that shorten the path and keep the arrow in place.

Answer (score 3):

You could use the Implies arrow tip instead. Or stop the line before the tip with the dot:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]
\tikzset{myline/.style={double distance=0.8pt, line width=0.4pt, -{>[length=2.5pt,width=4pt]}
         }}

    % axes
    \draw[red](1,-1)--(1,1);
    \draw[myline] (0,0) -- (1,0);
    \draw[double distance=0.8pt, line width=0.4pt, -{.>[length=2.5pt,width=4pt]}] (0,0.2) -- (1,0.2);
    \draw[double distance=0.8pt, line width=0.4pt, -{Implies[length=2.5pt,width=4pt]}] (0,0.4) -- (1,0.4);
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: (+1) `Implies` arrow is the solution! We learn everyday something here ;)

Comment: Thanks for this answer! I'm accepting the other answer as I wanted my particular arrow head.